# Why do we need an irony tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[irony](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irony) appears to have recently been added and it currently has a whopping 5 questions. How many (on-topic, non-duplicate) questions about irony are we expecting?

Comment: I can imagine "Is this sentence ironic?" being asked again and again.  I've had enough of it already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that [irony](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irony) is really a needed tag.

- [Is this an example of irony?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28419/is-this-an-example-of-irony)—the question could be simply tagged [rhetoric](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rhetoric), which is the other tag being used for that question
- [What are the similarities and differences between "irony" and "sarcasm"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26621/what-are-the-similarities-and-differences-between-irony-and-sarcasm)—the question doesn't use [sarcasm](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sarcasm); why should it use [irony](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irony)?
- [Is there a better / correct term for the de facto usage of ‘ironic’?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/is-there-a-better-correct-term-for-the-de-facto-usage-of-ironic)—the other tags already classify the question

Does [irony](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irony) focalize an aspect of the question that is not already covered from other tags? If the answer is yes, then [irony](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irony) should be kept. As far as I can see, it doesn't add anything to the questions, but this is my opinion.

Comment: And is *irony* really a classifier?  Are there questions that could be asked that are about irony that wouldn't use the word *irony*?  If not, then searching for the word irony is as good or better than searching for the tag, and the tag itself becomes pointless.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong about this, but I suspect that English speakers (and maybe Brits in particular) might be more disposed to 'ironical' turns of phrase than some others.

Ironically enough, I've only recently posted that I don't see much point in using *ironical* instead of *ironic*, but in the preceding sentence it did seem to flow a bit better.

Anyway, the point is that although it might be somewhat tedious to have people keep asking whether some sentence is ironic, the fact is they do. So if my initial postulate has any credibility, there might be people wanting to gain a better insight into the phenomenon by searching for the word within EL&U questions and answer text.

So I say keep it, and let's see how useful it turns out to be over time.

Comment: I don't see this as a good reason to have a _tag_ for irony. "Irony" is just a word; why does this particular word get its own tag?

Comment: @MrHen: Well, *if* I'm right that English is inherently more 'irony-laden' than many other languages, the tag might usefully apply to a number of questions having that less-than-transparent quality. *Slang*, *informal*, *idiom*, etc., are all just words too, but like *irony*, they can be helpful in categorising linguistic forms.